# Android webview, File upload, crashes when setting result in onActivityResult

Tags: android, webview, webchromeclient

In Android webview, when file upload option is clicked, onShowFileChooser is called where intent for user to select file to upload from image gallery is invoked.
after selecting file, inside onActivityResult it crashes due to following reason

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate showFileChooser result
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter$2.onReceiveValue(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:225)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter$2.onReceiveValue(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:220)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$4.onReceiveValue(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1063)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$4.onReceiveValue(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1047)
```

Answer (score 19):

```
@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    mActivity.setValueCallback(filePathCallback);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), Final.REQUEST_CODE_ALBUM);
    return true;
}
```

**return true**

Comment: "return true" was the part that fixed this problem for me. thank you.

Comment: Theres's also a `Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();` way.

Answer (score 6):

If you override `onShowFileChooser` and plan on calling `filePathCallback` to pass results, you must return true from `onShowFileChooser` which tells the underlying code not to pass a value to `filePathCallback`.

the true is basically saying "I will handle it"

Documentation: 
`@return true if filePathCallback will be invoked, false to use default handling.`

Comment: Any idea or link of if we set return false then how to manage? I am getting System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate showFileChooser result if set to false.

Comment: if you return false then you CAN NOT call `filePathCallback`

Answer (score 1):

either call `WebChromeClient#onShowFileChooser` with returning false and let the webview handle itself (default) or return true and then you can invoke `filePathCallback.onReceive` with null or array of uris

never both, otherwise webview receives 2 results from same 'question'

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to you will be taking data in uri and then making new object of uri array. In C# I have done below to resolve issue:
code which was givinf duplicate error:

```
  Android.Net.Uri result = data == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null :  data.Data ;
var a = new Android.Net.Uri[] { result };
```

Below code resolved the issue:

`Android.Net.Uri[] result = data == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : new Android.Net.Uri[] { data.Data };`